# Issue with 3rd person character movement

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a very simple movement script, where a player can use 'wasd' to make the character prefab forward, backward, left, and right.  I am using the following script to do so:

```
public class PlayerInput : MonoBehaviour {

   public Camera camera;
   public float speed;

   void Update () {     

      float horizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
      float vertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

      Debug.Log("horizontal: " + horizontal);
      Debug.Log("vertical: " + vertical);
      // Set character position 
      Vector3 direction = transform.position;
      if(horizontal != 0.0f || vertical != 0.0f) {
         if(vertical < 0.0f) {
                direction -= camera.transform.forward;
            } else if(vertical > 0.0f) {
                direction += camera.transform.forward;
            }
            if(horizontal < 0.0f) {
                direction -= camera.transform.right;
            } else if(horizontal > 0.0f) {
                direction += camera.transform.right;
            }               
            transform.Translate(direction * speed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }
}
```

However, my character only moves in the forward direction regardless of what key I am pushing down.  The camera is positioned behind my character within the same `character` prefab.  Why is my input only moving in the forward direction?

I can add pictures of my prefab and camera if that would help.

Answer (score 0):

I am silly.. I needed to new up my `Vector3 direction`...

`Vector3 direction = transform.position;` should be `Vector3 direction = new Vector3();`